# Remove useFormik lint issue when placed inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, formik, lint

The values from a dropdown is based on an API call whose array response is stored into a Zustand store. I have a useEffect that listens to when that Zustand store variable is no longer empty, it will automatically assign the first value in that array as the selected value in the form.

```
  const formik = useFormik()
  const store = useZustandStore()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (store.someSearchItems.length) {
      const initial = store.someSearchItems[0].value as string;

      formik.setFieldValue('LIST_VALUE', initial);
    }
  }, [store.someSearchItems]);
```

It does its job, however, I get the error `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'formik'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.` How do I workaround this lint issue without disabling it?

I tried including `formik` in the dependency array, but that executes the useEffect even if unrelated values inside the form is changed.

Comment: add this as the last line inside the useEffect: `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `useFormik` (your `formik` constant) changes on each render, because it contains the form values. However, `setFieldValue` (and other methods) is stable.

Instead of using the entire `formik` object, destructure `setFieldValue`, and use it in the `useEffect`, and it's dependencies.

```
const { setFieldValue } = useFormik()
const store = useZustandStore()

useEffect(() => {
  if (store.someSearchItems.length) {
    const initial = store.someSearchItems[0].value as string;

    setFieldValue('LIST_VALUE', initial);
  }
}, [store.someSearchItems, setFieldValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function listValue(){
    const initial = store.someSearchItems[0].value as string;

    formik.setFieldValue('LIST_VALUE', initial);
}

  useEffect(() => {
    if (store.someSearchItems.length) {
     listValue();
    }
  }, [listValue, store.someSearchItems]);
```

Alternatively, you can suppress the warning with this comment:
`// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Although, you can read more on why it is dangerous [here](https://react.dev/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#why-is-suppressing-the-dependency-linter-so-dangerous)

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (store.someSearchItems.length) {
      const initial = store.someSearchItems[0].value as string;

      formik.setFieldValue('LIST_VALUE', initial);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [store.someSearchItems]);
```